# Function with branch

Tags: python

Define function `print_popcorn_time()` with parameter `bag_ounces`. If `bag_ounces` is less than 3, print "Too small". If greater than 10, print "Too large". Otherwise, compute and print `6 * bag_ounces` followed by "seconds". End with a newline. Example output for `bag_ounces = 7`:

> 42 seconds.

For this program I'm getting suck on an error:

> ```
> "File "main.py", line 6
> elif bag_ounces = bag_ounces * 6"
>                 ^
> ```

```
def print_popcorn_time(bag_ounces):
    if bag_ounces < 3:
        print("Too small")
    elif bag_ounces > 10:
        print("Tool large")
    elif bag_ounces = bag_ounces * 6
    else:
        print(bag_ounces)

print_popcorn_time(7)
```

Comment: `=` is for assignment. You want `==` to compare.

Comment: I don't think he wants to compare, though.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Kevin I think you may be right. Now that I look at it again, I'm not entirely sure what his intent is there.

Answer (score 1):

Your last condition should just be `else`

```
def print_popcorn_time(bag_ounces):
    if bag_ounces < 3:
        print("Too small")
    elif bag_ounces > 10:
        print("Tool large")
    else:
        print('{} seconds'.format(bag_ounces * 6))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Here is the proper code. Tested in ZyBooks. The "else" print statement needed to be reformatted. Cheers.

```
def print_popcorn_time(bag_ounces):
    if bag_ounces < 3:
        print('Too small')
    elif bag_ounces > 10:
        print('Too large')
    else:
        print((bag_ounces * 6), 'seconds') 

print_popcorn_time(7)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_popcorn_time(bag_ounces):
if bag_ounces < 3:
    print('Too small')
elif bag_ounces > 10:
    print('Too large')
else:
    print(f'{bag_ounces * 6} seconds')
```

user_ounces = int(input())
print_popcorn_time(user_ounces)

Answer (score -1):

```
def print_popcorn_time(bag_ounces):
  if bag_ounces < 3:
    print("Too small")
    return



  if bag_ounces > 10:

    print("Too large")
    return



  else:

    print(str(6 * bag_ounces)+ " seconds")

user_ounces = int(input())
print_popcorn_time(user_ounces)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: Also, this question is over 5 years old and already has several answers. Are you entirely sure that this answer introduces something new? If so, what?